# How to automatically re-login a user with a cookie

Tags: php, web-applications, authentication, cookies

So on my application login form I've got one of those little boxes like `[_]`remember me

When the user checks that we set `$_COOKIE['rememberMe']` with the value of the username.  Now when that user comes back 3 days later, I obviously want to recognize them and re-log them in automatically.  It doesn't sound safe to simply check for the existence of that cookie and then use it's value as the username to login without a password.  But I'm not sure how else I would log them automatically...  Is there a way this usually done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your cookie should have three values:
1. username
2. expiration time
3. a session code

When a user logs in, generate a session code and set an expiration time.
Store that session code and expiration time in the cookie and on your database.

Then whenever user returns to the site, and if user is not logged in:
1. check for the cookie
2. check for the cookie against the database

If all three variable matches and the expiration time is not over, log the user in.

Alternatively, if you simply encode the session code as say a md5 of ($username.$expiration_time), then you won't have to set up a database for storing and checking. Although having a database with randomly generated session code is much safer.

Comment: exactly how i would do it also - thumbs up

Comment: So, @shiroin, should I use `session_id()` to generate a session code, or do you mean something less specialized like `mt_rand()` ?

Answer (score 2):

This is extremely unsafe. Since the cookie is the only thing you have to go by and the cookie is transferable from system to system, you would be vulnerable to cookie poisoning attacks and cookie copying attacks. If this is indeed the course you're set on, you will need to use some manner of foot-printing the user's system and storing that information in a database somewhere possibly as part of a persistent session on a session state server. This information could then be compared with the new login so if the cookie is transferred to a different system, it will not match and the automatic login will fail. As for accomplishing the login, I would recommend at a minimum to have a session state database where session information could be stored per session ID and username. If these 2 items are stored in the cookie, this information could then be used to get the information out of the database, and the foot-printing could be used as a stop-gap (although a very weak one) to prevent misuse.

Answer (score 1):

The only information you need to store in a cookie is some unique hash that's going to point to the right user session in your system. Storing username or other information is redundant and unsafe considering the fact that username can be captured by an attacker and used with a combination of other information. To make the system more safe, you should implement a layer that'd check user's location by the IP address and his browser details. I suggest you should learn from what companies like Facebook and Google do with user accounts.

Comment: Napalm, that's sort of helpful (the first part). But why don't _you_ explain more in depth exactly *what* companies like Facebook and Google do with user accounts.

Comment: For example, you can see all the active sessions for your user account in your settings. You can also manage them. Also, they check physical locations or ISPs that you login from and your browser/operating system footprint as an additional identification information.

Comment: You obviously are not someone who moves around. The IP address of my laptop will change many times a day. Keying the login to the IP address would make the method pretty much useless. Browser credentials, yes. IP address? No!

Comment: It's just a suggestion to make the system more safe, there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Place a random and uniqe hash in the cookie and store it in DB too with the current client's IP address.

If the user comes back, you can search for the hash in your DB.